# How to remove an XML element that contain the numeric part in their name in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Element like this <**A313**>1  in bold need to deleted where the tag name may be any thing A313,A312,pa123etc....

input is like this

```
 <para>
text........
</para>
   <A1234>
 </A1234>
 <para-numbar>
  this contain some information
  </para-number>
  <A141>
  </A141>
```

output is

```
<para>
      text........
 </para>

   <para-numbar>
   this contain some information
   </para-number>
```

Comment: If i understand you question you want to remove the '<' and '>'? I think the easiest way to do this is with a string.Replace() or Regex replace

Comment: It would help if you can explain exactly what is the requirements for removing a node. Are you removing any element with a number in, for example? It would be best if you showed your input XML, and your expected output too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(name() = translate(name(),'0123456789',''))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to a document, some element names in which contain digits, like the following**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <A314>xxx</A314>
  <b>
    <c221/>
  </b>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced, and in this case it is**:

```
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <b/>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** and its overriding.
2. The standard XPath **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)** function.

Answer (score 0):

This method defines whether string contains numbers:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasNumbers(this string s)
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and to remove elements with numbers from list:

```
List<string> list;
list.RemoveAll(str => str.HasNumbers());
```

Comment: it not solution for this i want to the remove only the tag name by xslt there are many tag contain numeric part